# Json allowget error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

This error comes up in our MVC app randomly. Sometimes doing the same exact thing it won't sometimes, it will. Does anyone know if this has to do with anything that could be a simple fix, or if this is something common that a lot of you have seen?

```
System.InvalidOperationException: This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.
   at System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass14.b__11()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass14.<>c__DisplayClass16.b__13()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass14.<>c__DisplayClass16.b__13()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass14.<>c__DisplayClass16.b__13()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__4()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Answer for your question was in the stack trace. "JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet"

So use it in your Controller as:

```
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

Comment: I think it might be a mistake to go around and blindly tell people to ignore the security reasons that AllowGet is disabled. -- It's not that hard to do a $.post instead to get the data and avoid the whole problem alltogether.

Comment: Good point. For those concerned Haack has a great article covering this: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx

Comment: The Haack article is now at: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/24/json-hijacking.aspx/

Answer (score 22):

You should read http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/24/json-hijacking.aspx/ before bypassing these security controls.

If you only expose your JSON data in response to a Http POST, then you are not vulnerable to this attack.

You can simply annotate your JSON action with [HttpPost] and in the client do something like

```
$.post('/blag/JSON', function (data) {
       //do something with my json data object here

});
```

Comment: It's entirely reasonable to accept a GET request when trying to receive JSON data. POSTs should be for creating a new record, or at the very least changing state. GET requests should be for retrieving data that does not affect state.

Comment: The reason the JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet solution above exists, is to ensure that the developer willfully bypasses this protection. The suggestion to use a post is to avoid a flaw in design/implementation that allows this data to be exposed to third parties. This is even shown in the first line of the stack trace:System.InvalidOperationException: This request **has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request**. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you call sometime the controller action per HTTP GET. To be able to return JSON results you should use code like

```
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
return Json(PartialView("index").ToJsonObject(this), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```